# CAMBIO VARIABLES EN EJECUCIÓN MODO DEBUG

Tags: java, netbeans, depuración, pruebas-unitarias

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación, y estoy haciendo una práctica para el instituto. Quizás esto que me está ocurriendo es normal, pero no lo sé, y por más que busco información, no se resuelve mi problema. Os cuento por si alguien me puede ayudar:

Estoy haciendo pruebas de escritorio con el modo debug de un programa hecho con java, usando Netbeans. A groso modo, os cuento que tengo un método, en el que hay una estructura de control. El programa pide que se introduzca una hora (el método es poner un reloj en hora) y la estructura de control controla que la hora no sea ni menor que 0 ni mayor que 23. Si se diera el caso que fuera menor que 0 o mayor que 23, tienen que mostrar por consola un mensaje que ponga error en hora.

Pues bien, cuando ejecuto el código de forma normal, todo funciona correctamente, y cuando doy un valor "correcto", se guarda la hora, y cuando doy un valor "erroneo", se imprime el mensaje.

La actividad me pide que haga todas las pruebas posibles, tanto con valores teoricamente correctos como con valores teoricamente falsos, usando el debug (junit viene luego, pero de primera, solo el modo debug), para comprobar todos los casos y si funciona como debe funcionar, y vaya haciendo capturas del valor de las variables en tiempo de ejecución, y que estos valores de las variables, los vaya cambiando sobre la marcha en tiempo de ejecución.

Pues bien, el problema que tengo es que en tiempo de ejecución, pongo un valor a la variable hora en negativo, por ejemplo, -12, y en lugar de tirar por el mensaje de error, me saca por la consola la hora actual, dando por bueno que el -12 es un número correcto, a pesar de la estructura de control.

¿Alguien sabe decirme que está pasando o si es normal o no?

Gracias por todo!!!!

Comment: Podes compartir la estructura del control que mencionas.(código)..

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.